# Exception: include(): realpath failed to canonicalize Service/Response.php - bailing

Tags: php, zend-framework, nginx

I am facing below issue:

> Exception: include(): realpath failed to canonicalize Service/Response.php - bailing

Below are my server configuration:

- OS- Debian
- Php- 5.2.x
- Mysql - 5.1.
- Nginx
- Zend

I have googled a lot but did not find any solution.

Comment: Smells like an APC issue. Do you have APC enabled? Do you still have the error if you turn it off?

Comment: Using an absolute path to the file instead will probably fix it too

Comment: @ Clement Herreman  .. ya it was an apc issue .. turning off APC solved it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to turn off APC, it would have been sufficient to set `apc.stat=1` in your apc.ini file. See also [this bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=59493).

Answer (score 1):

**OLD ANWSER:**

You can also use the function `require_once()`. This function will not give an error. The difference between include and require is that include gives an error and the script will continue running and with require the script will stop running.

**NEW ANWSER:**

I did some more research. The error doesn't come from `require_once()`,`require()` or `include()` but to fix this issue for APC-cache you need to set the absolute path, something like `/home/user/domains/example.com/public_html/include/config`. Include de base directory and the error is gone.

Comment: You can also downgrade your installation to version 3.1.9, the last stable version.

Answer (score 0):

Not overriding the `APC` settings (letting the default `APC` settings prevail) also solves this error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case and with Php 5.4, I downgraded to APC 3.1.10